# Ajax/jQuery Timing Issue

Tags: ajax, jquery, timing

I have a click function that does a jQuery/Ajax $.post to get data from a webservice when a span is clicked. When there is a Firebug break point set on the click function, everything works as expected (some new table tr's are appended to a table). When there is no break point set, nothing happens when you click the span. Firebug doesn't show any errors. I assume from other stackoverflow questions that this is a timing problem, but I don't know what to do about it. I have tried changing from a $.post to a $.ajax and setting async to false, but that didn't fix it. Here's the code for the click handler:

```
$('.rating_config').click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();
    var that = $(this);

    // calculate the name of the module based on the classes of the parent <tr>
    var mytrclasses = $(this).parents('tr').attr('class');
    var modulestart = mytrclasses.indexOf('module-');
    var start = mytrclasses.indexOf('-', modulestart) + 1;
    var stop = mytrclasses.indexOf(' ', start);
    var mymodule = mytrclasses.substring(start, stop);
    mymodule = mymodule.replace(/ /g, '+');
    mymodule = mymodule.replace(/_/g, '+');
    mymodule = encodeURI(mymodule);

    // calculate the name of the property based on the classes of the parent <tr>
    var propertystart = mytrclasses.indexOf('property-');
    var propstart = mytrclasses.indexOf('-', propertystart) + 1;
    var propstop = mytrclasses.indexOf(' ', propstart);
    var myproperty = mytrclasses.substring(propstart, propstop);
    myproperty = myproperty.replace(/ /g, '+');
    myproperty = myproperty.replace(/_/g, '+');
    myproperty = encodeURI(myproperty);
    var parentspanid = $(this).attr('id');

    // Remove the comparison rows if they are already present, otherwise generate them
    if ($('.comparison_' + parentspanid).length != 0) {
        $('.comparison_' + parentspanid).remove();
    } else {
        $.post('http://localhost/LearnPHP/webservice.php?user=user-0&q=comparison&level=property&module=' + mymodule + '&version_id=1.0&property=' + myproperty + '&format=xml', function(data) {
            var data = $.xml2json(data);

            for (var propnum in data.configuration.modules.module.properties.property) {
                var prop = data.configuration.modules.module.properties.property[propnum];
                console.log(JSON.stringify(prop));
                prop.mod_or_config = 'config';
                var item_id = mymodule + '?' + prop.property_name + '?' + prop.version_id + '?' + prop.value;
                item_id = convertId(item_id);
                prop.id = item_id;
                //alert('prop.conformity = ' + prop.conformity);
                // genRow(row, module, comparison, comparison_parentspanid)
                var rowstring = genRow(prop, mymodule, true, parentspanid);
                console.log('back from genRow. rowstring = ' + rowstring);
                $(that).closest('tr').after(rowstring);
                //$('tr#node-' + data[row].id + ' span#rating' + row.id).css('background', '-moz-linear-gradient(left, #ff0000 0%, #ff0000 ' + data[row].conformity + '%, #00ff00 ' + 100 - data[row].conformity + '%, #00ff00 100%');
                var conformity_color = getConformityColor(prop.conformity);
                $('tr#comparison_module_' + mymodule + '_setting_' + prop.id + ' span#module_' + mymodule + '_rating' + prop.id).css({'background':'-moz-linear-gradient(left, ' + conformity_color + ' 0%, ' + conformity_color + ' ' + prop.conformity + '%, #fffff0 ' + prop.conformity + '%, #fffff0 100%)'});
                //$('tr#comparison-' + data[row].id + ' span#rating' + data[row].id).css('background','-webkit-linear-gradient(left,  #00ff00 0%, #00ff00 ' + data[row].conformity + '%, #ff0000 ' + (100 - (data[row].conformity + 2)) + '%, #ff0000 100%)');

            }
        });
        // Hide the Fix by mod column
        hideFixedByModCol();

        $('tr.comparison_' + parentspanid).each(function(i){
                if (i % 2 == 0) {
                    $(that).addClass('comparison_even');
                } else {
                    $(that).addClass('comparison_odd');
                }
            });
    }

  });
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I suspect your data is coming back improperly formed. Enclose your code from the break on within `try {} catch {}` to see the error generated. Also it would be a good idea to add error processing to your ajax request.

Comment: OK, I've put in several try{} catch{} blocks, but I'm still not catching any errors. I've looked at the XML I'm getting back from the $.post in Firebug, and I just don't see any problems with it. And it's getting processed by the xml2json module without any problem. I'm still confused.

Comment: If you add `<div id='myerror'></div>` to your `HTML` and add `$('#myerror').text('inside');` to the first line of the function without the break does the text appear in the new div?  Did you add error handling to the ajax request?

Comment: "inside" shows up when I have the break point, but not when I don't have the breakpoint. I did add error handling to the ajax request, but it doesn't show errors.

Comment: Make a jsbin.com, and I will take a look.

Comment: It turns out that the problem was a $.post earlier in the code that was affecting this jQuery selector somehow. When I changed that $.post to a $.ajax and set async to false, this code started to run correctly outside of the debugger. So the clues were that this click handler wasn't getting called outside of Firebug, even when I reduced it to the point where all it did was show an alert, and other articles on stackoverflow indicating that when something works in Firebug and not outside of it, there is probably an Ajax timing issue. Thanks, shaun5.